# Что быстрее: Yii2 DataProvider "SORT" против SQL "ORDER BY"

Tags: sql, база-данных, yii2, yii, gridview

В Yii2 есть провайдер данных, например ActiveDataProvider(ADP).
В нем возможна настройка сортировки по выбранному полю.
У меня вопрос, что выполнится быстрее.
Обычный запрос через построитель запросов в Yii2 с ORDER BY или SORT в ADP?
В моем случае есть пагинация на странице.
Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Я думаю что сервер базы данных отсортирует быстрее (особенно если на поле по которому сортируют индекс), чем "универсальный" клиент. Но если клиент мощнее чем сервер СУБД, то может быть наоборот. Тут вы выбираете сами кого лучше нагрузить: клиент или сервер.

Comment: А провайдер разве не делает такой же запрос в БД?